# How to use BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage() to set a custom Marker icon?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to set a custom icon for the markers of my map, in my Flutter app. Since `BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset()` is deprecated, I'm sruggling to find how to use `BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage()`.

I did not find any doc or Stackoverflow question about this.

This is the current way I'm creating it (without the custom image):

```dart
Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(pos.toString()),
          position: pos,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: store['store_name'],
            snippet: '',
          ),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker));
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Define a field in Class:

```
BitmapDescriptor myIcon;
```

Retrieve icon before the Map is ready.

```
@override
void initState() {
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), 'assets/my_icon.png')
        .then((onValue) {
      myIcon = onValue;
    });
 }
```

set the Icon:

```
icon: myIcon;
```

Make sure you have set the icon in Flutter section of pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the clear answer. Marked as solution.

Comment: @MickaëlD Always happy to help :)

Comment: Hello guys, I've loaded icon in initState before app loads, I confirmed it with loggers but after page loads I see an error `com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.a: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.'
Can anyone help ? Many thanks

Comment: I follow the step above it  no any error but marker not display I don't know why

Comment: i'll try to use but return error .. software say Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap. how to solve? thanks

Comment: @durduliu2009 I found using a `png` image works. I had the same error, but mine was because I had a slash in front of `assets`, like `/assets/icon.png`. Changing it to `assets/icon.png` solved the issue for me.

Comment: For some reason, I found that changing `Size(48, 48)` to `Size(10, 10)` does not change the size of the icon.

Comment: @JVE999 Size param of `ImageConfiguration` is Ignored by `BitmapDescriptor`

Comment: Hi all, Do you encounter problems with sizing the icon? In my case it does not want to size to the desired value. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AksharPatel question if I have multiple icons how should I do that?

Comment: my app crashes when i tried this way....

Answer (score 24):

A better solution will be to wrap the **GoogleMap** widget inside a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). 
Generate your markers in a separate Future, and assign the result of the future
to the markers in the GoogleMap widget

FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: generateMarkers(positions),
  initialData: Set.of(<Marker>[]),
  builder: (context, snapshot) => GoogleMap(        
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0, 0)),
    markers: snapshot.data,
  ),
);
```

markers generator:

```
Future<Set<Marker>> generateMarkers(List<LatLng> positions) async {
List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];
for (final location in positions) {    
  final icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(size: Size(24, 24)), 'assets/my_icon.png');

  final marker = Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(location.toString()),
    position: LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
    icon: icon,
  );

  markers.add(marker);
}

return markers.toSet();

}
```

Comment: You should have extracted  `final icon =...` from the loop, to speed the code up.

Comment: @Sos. yes you are correct, if we are using bitmap for each marker, then the icon should be taken out of the loop. However, if there is a logic for using different bitmaps for the markers, then it will stay in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You could use it like:

```
Marker marker = Marker(
        icon: await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), 'assets/images/pin.png'
        )
    );
```

Comment: where to put async?