# apple_maps_flutter - I want to use an image as a marker on the map

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, apple-maps, fluttermap

I get the following error when using the code in the photo:

*The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BitmapDescriptor'*

[image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60221038/11118209